# Error Passing javascript values using Url.action()

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am using url.action to pass values to my controller

with the below example

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("result", "Checking", new { id = "Name" })'">
```

it comes out with an error of

> Unhandled exception at line 185, column 13 in http://localhost:51086/Checking/result/Name
>   0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

while the program works fine with

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("result", "Checking")?id=Name'">
```

Would like to know the difference of passing value using routevalue of Url.Action

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're using a `location.href` inside an onclick? I  am assuming that all you want to to is go to a controller method and return a `View`. Why don't you just use the `@Url.Action()`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(\"result\", \"Checking\", new { id = \"Name\" })'">
```